# Finding all cars who use the same parts types

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlite

Given tables:

```
parts (part_id, part_desc, type_id, car_id)
types (type_id, type_name)
cars (car_id, car_model, car_make)
```

I want to find id, model and make of cars who have parts for all the types of parts belonging to the make 'Honda' and model 'Civic'. That is, if Honda Civic has types `A,B,C` then it will find all cars who has parts belonging to `A` AND `B` and `C`.

I am unsure how to do this, but I manage to do it for `A` OR `B` OR `C`

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.car_id, c.car_model, c.car_make
FROM cars c, parts p
WHERE c.car_id= p.car_id AND p.type_id IN (
       SELECT p.type_id FROM cars c, parts p
       WHERE a.car_id = p.car_id
       AND a.car_model = 'Civic' 
       AND a.car_make = 'Honda'
)
```

Where the innerquery gets all types of parts for Honda Civic, but the IN() clause will match cars if they have only 1 of the `A,B,C` and not the all.

I want to avoid the use of `ALL` and `ANY` set operators. Also `A,B,C` was an example and not to be taken literally with it hard-coded in the answer. The results will be unknown of the subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid words like "all", reformulate the question by using two negations:
You want cars for which no type exists that the Honda Civic has but that this car does not have.

```
SELECT *
FROM cars
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM types CivicTypes
                  JOIN parts CivicParts USING (type_id)
                  WHERE car_id = (SELECT car_id
                                  FROM cars
                                  WHERE car_make = 'Honda'
                                    AND car_model = 'Civic')
                    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                    FROM types JOIN parts USING (type_id)
                                    WHERE type_id = CivicTypes.type_id
                                      AND car_id = cars.car_id)
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as ( -- first find out all the type_id belonging to Honda civic
select distinct p.type_id
  from cars c
      ,parts p
 where c.car_model = 'Civic' 
   and c.car_make = 'Honda'
   and c.car_id = p.car_id
)  
,c as ( -- find which car has which part types
select distinct
       c.car_id
      ,c.car_make
      ,c.car_model
      ,t.type_id
  from t
      ,parts p
      ,cars  c
 where t.type_id = p.type_id
   and p.car_id = c.car_id
)
-- the number of the records in c for each car meeting conditions must be equal to 
-- the number of part types
select c.car_id
      ,c.car_make
      ,c.car_model
  from c
 group
    by c.car_id
      ,c.car_make
      ,c.car_model
having count(0) = (select count(0) from t)
```